# How to refactor reduce with array value

Tags: javascript, refactoring, gis, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to clean up code.

`selectedGroup.items` looks like this (simplified):

```
[
  { szenarien: [{extent: {xmin: 1, xmax: 2, ymin: 3, ymax: 4}}, ...] },
  { extent: {...}] } // Extent has same properties as above
]
```

Below is my mapping code. Goal: Get the outermost points of a collection of polygons

```
 const coordinateValues = selectedGroup.items.reduce(
  //TODO: Make this a bit more readable
  (acc, item) => {
    // item is a group
    if (item.szenarios) {
      item.szenarios.map((szenario) => {
        acc.xmin.push(szenario.extent.xmin);
        acc.xmax.push(szenario.extent.xmax);
        acc.ymin.push(szenario.extent.ymin);
        acc.ymax.push(szenario.extent.ymax);
      });
    }
    // item is a szenario
    else {
      acc.xmin.push(item.extent.xmin);
      acc.xmax.push(item.extent.xmax);
      acc.ymin.push(item.extent.ymin);
      acc.ymax.push(item.extent.ymax);
    }
    return acc;
  },
  { xmin: [], xmax: [], ymin: [], ymax: [] }
);

// Prepare an extent with the smallest xmin, ymin and the biggest xmax, ymax to have all szenarios in it
const calculatedGroupExtent: __esri.Extent = new EsriExtent({
  xmax: Math.max(...coordinateValues.xmax) + 200,
  xmin: Math.min(...coordinateValues.xmin) - 200,
  ymax: Math.max(...coordinateValues.ymax) + 200,
  ymin: Math.min(...coordinateValues.ymin) - 200,
  spatialReference: { wkid: 2056 },
});
```

Obviously it's not really readable. I can't find a beautiful way to simplify it without adding many "readability constants" (and thus having no improvement)

Comment: Probably you could find answers or better to ask here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a mix of both answers:

```
const pointIdentifiers = ['xmin', 'xmax', 'ymin', 'ymax'];
// Get all coordinates of the group's szenarios
const coordinateValues = selectedGroup.items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  // Differenciate if item is a szenario itself or a group (with szenarios)
  const szenarios = item.szenarios ? item.szenarios : [item];

  // Add every point for every szenario
  szenarios.forEach((valueItem) => {
    pointIdentifiers.forEach((identifier) => {
      acc[identifier].push(valueItem.extent[identifier]);
    });
  });
  return acc;
}, Object.fromEntries(pointIdentifiers.map((prop) => [prop, []])));

// Prepare an extent with the smallest xmin, ymin and the biggest xmax, ymax to have all szenarios in it
const calculatedGroupExtent: __esri.Extent = new EsriExtent({
  xmax: Math.max(...coordinateValues.xmax) + 200,
  xmin: Math.min(...coordinateValues.xmin) - 200,
  ymax: Math.max(...coordinateValues.ymax) + 200,
  ymin: Math.min(...coordinateValues.ymin) - 200,
  spatialReference: { wkid: 2056 },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a helper function that takes a `szenario` object and pushes each of the `['xmin', 'xmax', 'ymin', 'ymax']` properties to the appropriate array. Then, while iterating over items, you just need to test whether the item is a group (in which case you'd do `item.szenarios.forEach(addSzenario)`), otherwise add the single szenario: `addSzenario(item.extent)`

```
const props = ['xmin', 'xmax', 'ymin', 'ymax'];
const coordinateValues = Object.fromEntries(
  props.map(prop => [prop, []])
);
const addSzenario = (szenario) => {
  for (const prop of props) {
    coordinateValues[prop].push(szenario[prop]);
  }
};
for (const item of selectedGroup.items) {
  // item is a group
  if (item.szenarios) {
    item.szenarios.forEach(addSzenario);
  } else {
    addSzenario(item.extent);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use reduce to compute the max and min.

```
const getVal = (item) => {
  return item.szenarios ? szenario.extent[key] : item.extent[key];
}

const getMin = (group, key) => {
  return group.items.reduce((acc, item) => {
    return Math.min(acc, getVal(item));
  }, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER); 
}

const getMax = (group, key) => {
  return group.items.reduce((acc, item) => {
    return Math.max(acc, getVal(item));
  }, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER); 
}


const xmin = getMin(selectedGroup, "xmin");
const xmax = getMin(selectedGroup, "xmax");
const ymin = getMin(selectedGroup, "ymin");
const ymax = getMin(selectedGroup, "ymax");
```